# STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION error occurred when send data from Rust to C# DLL

Tags: c#, dll, rust

I have been facing an issue when I send the string data from Rust to C# DLL. Rust exe will show the following error.

`error: process didn't exit successfully: target\release\test.exe (exit code: 0xc0000374, STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION)`

The Rust exe will crash after I sent the data for a few times (No exact pattern).

Below is the code on how the Rust communicate with C# DLL.

```
extern crate libloading;

fn call_dynamic(arg_1_str: &str, arg_2_int: i32) -> Result<i32, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {

    let arg_1_c_str = CString::new(arg_str_1).unwrap();

    // This is intended 
    let arg_3_c_str = CString::new("").unwrap();

    let arg_1_c_char = arg_1_c_str.as_ptr();
    let arg_3_c_char = arg_3_c_str.as_ptr();

    let lib = libloading::Library::new("Test.dll").unwrap();
    unsafe {
        let func: libloading::Symbol<
            unsafe fn(
                arg_1: *const c_char,
                arg_2: i32,
                arg_3: *const c_char,
            ) -> i32,
        > = lib
            .get(b"GetStatus")
            .unwrap();

        Ok(func(arg_1_c_char, arg_2_int, arg_3_c_char))
    }
}
```

The library that used to communicate with external DLL is libloading.

What could possible cause this error to be happened and is there any way to overcome the issue? Your help is much appreciated.

**Note:** I have no access to the source code of the C# DLL. Hence, I have no idea what is happening inside.

Here's some Java code that works. I'm trying to do the same thing in Rust:

```java
public interface TestDLL extends Library { 
    int GetStatus (String arg1, int arg2, String arg3);
}

public int GetStatusFromDLL (String arg1, int arg2) {
    TestDLL test_dll = (TestDLL)Native.loadLibrary ("Test", TestDLL.class);
    return test_dll.GetStatus (arg1, arg2, null);
}
```

Comment: Do you know if the C# DLL keeps a reference to either of the input strings after the call returns? Because _Rust_ will free them at the end of `call_dynamic`, so you will have issues if the C# DLL attempts to use them later.

Comment: Unless the dll was built with ffi in mind, you're going to have a hard time. Even if so, your `unsafe fn` is missing a calling convention, so it'll use Rust's ABI which is almost definitely wrong. I'm not confident on the layout of C# `string`s, but I'd bet that a single `char*` isn't going to work. Can you provide the C# type signature of the `GetStatus` function?

Comment: @Jmb The C# DLL is a standalone DLL (without exe attached). So, I assume the usage of the DLL is ended when exit from `call_dynamic` function. Is that any way to let C# to release the string memory instead of Rust doing this?

Comment: @kmdreko The type signature of `GetStatus` in C# is `int GetStatus(string, int , string)`. The above function managed to get the string that pass from Rust to C# as C# there will print a log for me to see what I passed in.

Comment: Visual Studio provides tool named ILdasm (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/framework/tools/ildasm-exe-il-disassembler). Could you look a signature of function using this?

Comment: @AngelicosPhosphoros The followings is the output from the tool. `public static method int32 *(int8*,int32,int8*)`. Apparently, I was told with another story by other developer since this DLL is some kind of legacy stuff without well documented =x.

Comment: Are both `int8*` strict input arguments, or will `GetStatus` attempt to write to one of them? Because if it writes, you will need to ensure that there is enough allocated memory there to hold the result.

Comment: @Jmb Are you saying I must pass in value for both the `int8*`? The first `int8*` is the key argument for the function while the second `int8*` in can be null or empty string. For "`GetStatus` attempt to write to one of them part", I don't really get what you mean over here. A little note here, I have no access to the source code of the DLL and I could not know what is happening inside.

Comment: Even if you don't have the source code for the DLL, do you have at least some doc for `GetStatus` or some example C# or C code that calls it? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: @Jmb Basically, the function is to get the license status. It will check the license based on the arguments that I passed in then return me a status code in integer form. I don't think the DLL will alter the arguments `(int8*, int32, int8*)` that I passed in. I have one example that is in Java. ```public interface TestDLL extends Library { int GetStatus(String arg1, int arg2, String arg3); } public int GetStatusFromDLL(String arg1, int arg2) { TestDLL test_dll = (TestDLL) Native.loadLibrary("Test", TestDLL.class); return test_dll.GetStatus(arg1, arg2, null); }```

Comment: The only difference I see between your Java and Rust codes is that in Java the third argument is a null pointer whereas in Rust you pass an empty string. What happens if you use `ptr::null()` as the third argument?

Comment: @Jmb I have tried with your method which replace third argument with `ptr::null()`. So far, I didn't encounter with any STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION issue anymore. I think my problem should considered as solved. Thanks for your help. You just saved my day =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved by changing the third argument `arg_3_c_str` from an empty string to null pointer `ptr::null()`. The final solution is as below.

```
fn call_dynamic(arg_1_str: &str, arg_2_int: i32) -> Result<i32, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {

    let arg_1_c_str = CString::new(arg_str_1).unwrap();
    let arg_1_c_char = arg_1_c_str.as_ptr();

    let lib = libloading::Library::new("Test.dll").unwrap();
    unsafe {
        let func: libloading::Symbol<
            unsafe fn(
                arg_1: *const c_char,
                arg_2: i32,
                arg_3: *const c_char,
            ) -> i32,
        > = lib
            .get(b"GetStatus")
            .unwrap();

        Ok(func(arg_1_c_char, arg_2_int, ptr::null()))
    }
}
```

All credits goes to @Jmb as he pointed out the difference between the Rust and Java implementations.

But, still there is another interesting point to discuss why passing in an empty string instead of null pointer will cause STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION error.

Comment: Given the absence of doc, I suspect that `arg3` is in fact some kind of "details" output argument, which if not null should be a given size (or maybe a given type) and that `GetStatus` tries to put some extra status information there. When you pass an empty string, `GetStatus` tries to replace it with these details, but there is not enough space so it overwrites some of Rust's heap housekeeping data.